# Both speaker and microphone via I2S

Tags: pi-zero-w, i2s

I got the exact same error as someone asked on the raspberry pi forums. But no solution was found yet. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=183617

I've connected max98357-i2s to the Rpi via I2S and it's working ok. https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/raspberry-pi-usage

Now I'm trying to connect a microphone also via I2S. What I did was following the instructions in the following page:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout?view=all

Somewhere in the middle, it says:
Download the module, written by Paul Creaser

```
git clone https://github.com/PaulCreaser/rpi-i2s-audio
cd rpi-i2s-audio
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r )/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo insmod my_loader.ko
```

Verify that the module was loaded:

```
lsmod | grep my_loader
dmesg | tail
```

But in dmesg I get:

```
bcm2835-i2s 20203000.i2s: Trying to bind component to card
"snd_rpi_simple_card" but is already bound to card
"snd_rpi_hifiberry_dac"

asoc-simple-card asoc-simple-card.0: ASoC: failed to instantiate card
-19
```

It seems that the mic is trying to bind to the same sound card the speaker is bound to. What can I do? Is there another option to connect both mic and speaker to I2S?

Comment: Hy Greg, have you made some progress with your problem. I seem to have the same issue: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90647/i2s-recording-combined-with-i2s-playback

Comment: @Besi No, I did not have time to look into this any further.